# Как открыть диалог QML в UI форме?

Tags: c++, qt, ui, qml

Нашёл [popup календарь](https://evileg.com/ru/post/178/) реализованный с помощью QML. Хочу его встроить в свою программу, но у меня основное окно программы ui форма. Как мне по нажатию на line Edit  открыть календарь реализованный с помощью QML и передать выбранную дату в line Edit?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
popupCalendar.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Item {
    property var tempDate: new Date();

    Dialog {
         id: dialogCalendar
         // Задаём размеры диалогового окна
         width: 250
         height: 300

         // Создаем контент диалогового окна
         contentItem: Rectangle {
             id: dialogRect
             color: "#f7f7f7"

             // Первым идёт кастомный календарь
             Calendar {
                 id: calendar
                 // Размещаем его в верхней части диалога и растягиваем по ширине
                 anchors.top: parent.top
                 anchors.left: parent.left
                 anchors.right: parent.right
                 anchors.bottom: row.top

                 // Стилизуем Календарь
                 style: CalendarStyle {

                     // Стилизуем navigationBar
                     navigationBar: Rectangle {
                         /* Он будет состоять из прямоугольника,
                          * в котором будет располагаться две кнопки и label
                          * */
                         height: 48
                         color: "#f7f7f7"

                         /* Горизонтальный разделитель,
                          * который отделяет navigationBar от поля с  числами
                          * */
                         Rectangle {
                             color: "#d7d7d7"
                             height: 1
                             width: parent.width
                             anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                         }

                         // Кнопка промотки месяцев назад
                         Button {
                             id: previousMonth
                             width: parent.height - 8
                             height: width
                             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                             anchors.left: parent.left
                             anchors.leftMargin: 8

                             /* По клику по кнопке вызываем функцию
                              * календаря, которая отматывает месяц назад
                              * */
                             onClicked: control.showPreviousMonth()

                             // Стилизуем кнопку
                             style: ButtonStyle {
                                 background: Rectangle {
                                     // Окрашиваем фон кнопки
                                     color: "#f7f7f7"
                                     /* И помещаем изображение, у которго будет
                                      * два источника файлов в зависимости от того
                                      * нажата кнопка или нет
                                      */
                                     Image {
                                         source: control.pressed ? "left_arrow_disable.png" : "left_arrow.png"
                                         width: parent.height - 8
                                         height: width
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }

                         // Помещаем стилизованный label
                         Label {
                             id: dateText
                             /* Забираем данные из title календаря,
                              * который в данном случае не будет виден
                              * и будет заменён данным label
                              */
                             text: styleData.title
                             color:  "#34aadc"
                             elide: Text.ElideRight
                             horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                             font.pixelSize: 16
                             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                             anchors.left: previousMonth.right
                             anchors.leftMargin: 2
                             anchors.right: nextMonth.left
                             anchors.rightMargin: 2
                         }

                         // Кнопка промотки месяцев вперёд
                         Button {
                             id: nextMonth
                             width: parent.height - 8
                             height: width
                             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                             anchors.right: parent.right

                             /* По клику по кнопке вызываем функцию
                              * календаря, которая отматывает месяц назад
                              * */
                             onClicked: control.showNextMonth()

                              // Стилизуем кнопку
                             style: ButtonStyle {
                                 // Окрашиваем фон кнопки
                                 background: Rectangle {
                                     color: "#f7f7f7"
                                     /* И помещаем изображение, у которго будет
                                      * два источника файлов в зависимости от того
                                      * нажата кнопка или нет
                                      */
                                     Image {
                                         source: control.pressed ? "right_arrow_disable.png" : "right_arrow.png"
                                         width: parent.height - 8
                                         height: width
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }


                     // Стилизуем отображением квадратиков с числами месяца
                     dayDelegate: Rectangle {
                         anchors.fill: parent
                         anchors.margins: styleData.selected ? -1 : 0
                         // Определяем цвет в зависимости от того, выбрана дата или нет
                         color: styleData.date !== undefined && styleData.selected ? selectedDateColor : "transparent"

                         // Задаём предопределённые переменные с цветами, доступные только для чтения
                         readonly property color sameMonthDateTextColor: "#444"
                         readonly property color selectedDateColor: "#34aadc"
                         readonly property color selectedDateTextColor: "white"
                         readonly property color differentMonthDateTextColor: "#bbb"
                         readonly property color invalidDateColor: "#dddddd"

                         // Помещаем Label для отображения числа
                         Label {
                             id: dayDelegateText
                             text: styleData.date.getDate() // Устанавливаем число в текущий квадрат
                             anchors.centerIn: parent
                             horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                             font.pixelSize: 10

                             // Установка цвета
                             color: {
                                 var theColor = invalidDateColor; // Устанавливаем невалидный цвет текста
                                 if (styleData.valid) {
                                     /* Определяем цвет текста в зависимости от того
                                      * относится ли дата к выбранному месяцу или нет
                                      * */
                                     theColor = styleData.visibleMonth ? sameMonthDateTextColor : differentMonthDateTextColor;
                                     if (styleData.selected)
                                         // Перекрашиваем цвет текста, если выбрана данная дата в календаре
                                         theColor = selectedDateTextColor;
                                 }
                                 theColor;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             // Делаем панель с кнопками
             Row {
                 id: row
                 height: 48
                 anchors.left: parent.left
                 anchors.right: parent.right
                 anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

                 // Кнопка для закрытия диалога
                 Button {
                     id: dialogButtonCalCancel
                     anchors.top: parent.top
                     anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                     width: parent.width / 2 - 1

                     style: ButtonStyle {
                         background: Rectangle {
                             color: control.pressed ? "#d7d7d7" : "#f7f7f7"
                             border.width: 0
                         }

                         label: Text {
                             text: qsTr("Cancel")
                             font.pixelSize: 14
                             color: "#34aadc"
                             verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                             horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                         }
                     }
                     // По нажатию на кнопку - просто закрываем диалог
                     onClicked: dialogCalendar.close()
                 }

                 // Вертикальный разделитель между кнопками
                 Rectangle {
                     id: dividerVertical
                     width: 2
                     anchors.top: parent.top
                     anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                     color: "#d7d7d7"
                 }

                 // Кнопка подтверждения выбранной даты
                 Button {
                     id: dialogButtonCalOk
                     anchors.top: parent.top
                     anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                     width: parent.width / 2 - 1

                     style: ButtonStyle {
                         background: Rectangle {
                             color: control.pressed ? "#d7d7d7" : "#f7f7f7"
                             border.width: 0
                         }

                         label: Text {
                             text: qsTr("Ok")
                             font.pixelSize: 14
                             color: "#34aadc"
                             verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                             horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                         }
                     }

                     /* По клику по кнопке сохраняем выбранную дату во временную переменную
                      * и помещаем эту дату на кнопку в главном окне,
                      * после чего закрываем диалог
                      */
                     onClicked: {
                         tempDate = calendar.selectedDate
                         button.text = Qt.formatDate(tempDate, "dd.MM.yyyy");
                         dialogCalendar.close();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         /* Данная функция необходима для того, чтобы
          * установить дату с кнопки в календарь,
          * иначе календарь откроется с текущей датой
          */
         function show(x){
             calendar.selectedDate = x
             dialogCalendar.open()
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, эта панель должна быть всплывающим окном. Можно просто на стороне C++ загружать её в `QQuickView`, и дальше работать как с обычным `QWidget`. Единственная проблема - в `QQuickView` практически не работает компоновка по содержимому (точнее, текущий размер определяется, а минимальный - нет), из-за чего приходится либо устанавливать политику `QSizePolicy::Fixed`, либо задавать минимальный размер вручную.

Еще можно использовать `QQuickWindow`, который не является наследников `QWidget`, по нему ничего посоветовать не могу.

Если QML будет выводиться в подготовленное место на UI - можно использовать `QQuickView` на UI.

Можно подключаться к сигналам от QML через `rootObject()`, через него же можно извлекать и устанавливать свойства.

```
QObject *item = view.rootObject();

MyClass myClass;
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                 &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
```